# Entity Framework Code first wrong saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, local-database

I'm having a problem understanding how EF is saving my entities.
I have my `DbContext`:

```
    public DbSet<Hero> MyHeroes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SpecialItem> SpecialItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Weapon> MyWeapons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WeaponHolder> MyWeaponHolders { get; set; }
```

My "Main" entity is `Hero`, it inherit from `Character`:

```
public class Character
    {
        [Key]
        public int CharacterID { get; set; }
        [Column("name")]
        protected string name;
        [Column("maxLife")]
        protected int maxHitPoint;
        [Column("actualLife")]
        protected int actualHitPoint;
        [Column("baseAgility")]
        protected int baseAgility;
    }
public class Hero : Character
    {
        [Column("Gold")]
        private int gold;
        public WeaponHolder weaponHolder;
        public List<SpecialItem> specialItems;
    }
```

It contains a `WeaponHolder`:

```
public class WeaponHolder
    {
        [Key]
        public int WeaponHolderID { get; set; }
        [Column("weaponHolderSize")]
        private int weaponHolderSize;
        List<Weapon> weapons;
    }
```

which can contain several `Weapon`:

```
 public class Weapon : Loot
    {
        [Column("name")]
        string name;
        [Column("WeaponType")]
        WeaponTypes weaponType;
    }
```

I'm creating a `Hero` and give him several `SpecialItems`, and a `weaponHolder` with several `Weapon`.  When I'm trying to save my `Hero`, using

```
heroContext.MyHeroes.Add(hero);
```

it does save it's `SpecialItems` but it doesn't save its `WeaponHolder` and content.  If I do save my `weaponHolder` "manually" using

```
heroContext.MyWeaponHolders.Add(hero.weaponHolder);
```

then it does as expected save the `WeaponHolder` and its `Weapons`.

I noticed that EF did not create a foreign key between `Hero` and `WeaponHolder`, but I did add one manually and did not notice any change in the saving comportement.

Why isn't EF automatically saving my `Hero`'s `WeaponHolder` when I am saving my `Hero`?  Can I save it manually? If so, how can I retrieve my `Hero` primary Key as soon as I save him in order to manually link my `WeaponHolder` foreign key to the right value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Brian Mains I managed to get it to work.
I was missing a lot of getter/setter in order to be able to retrieve properly my properties.
And I indeed had to add a new ID field per Key, and put my `[ForeignKey("...")]` on it.

My code now looks like that :

```
public class Character
    {
        [Key]
        public int CharacterID { get; set; }
        [Column("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Column("maxLife")]
        protected int maxHitPoint{ get; set; }
        [Column("actualLife")]
        protected int actualHitPoint{ get; set; }
        [Column("baseAgility")]
        protected int baseAgility{ get; set; }
    }

public class Hero : Character
    {
        [ForeignKey("weaponHolder")]
        public int WeaponHolderID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("backPack")]
        public int BackPackID { get; set; }
        [Column("Gold")]
        private int gold{ get; set; }
        public WeaponHolder weaponHolder{ get; set; }
        public List<SpecialItem> specialItems{ get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With a single entity in Hero (like the WeaponHolder property), it would also have the reference to the ID in it like

```
public int WeaponHolderID { get; set; }
```

That is missing from this implementation.  Is the relationship you are referring to setup correctly?

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding your answer correctly.  
Do you mean that I should add `public int WeaponHolderID { get; set; }` to my `Hero` class ?  
I was under the assumption that EF took care of create the foreign key in case of one to one relationship.

Comment: It is highly based on there being an ID property. There is no true 1 to 1 relationship; it always treats one of the sides as a one to many.  If Hero is the PK in the relationship, yes it should have WeaponHolderID as a property, but if WeaponHolder is the PK, Hero should have a List of WeaponHolder objects and no WeaponHolderID property.